# TypeWriter Effect no inline with heading

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a portfolio website using react and I wanted to print some of my hobbies using a typewriter effect

Currently, my code is functioning as

"I like to" 
[hobbies]

I would like it to function as

"I like to" [hobbies]

Here's my react code

```
<div className="row banner">
    <div className="banner-text">
        <h1 className="responsive-headline">I am {resumeData.name}.</h1>
        <h3>I am a {resumeData.role}.{resumeData.roleDescription}</h3>
        <div className="typewriter-home">
            <h2>I like
                <Typical loop={Infinity}
                  steps={['Coding', 2000,'Soccer', 2000, 
                          'Basketball', 2000, 'Finance', 2000,
                          'Tech', 2000]}/></h2>
         </div>
```

CSS

```
.typewriter-home {
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: We've no idea what elements Typical is generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at https://github.com/catalinmiron/react-typical it looks like you can set a wrapper prop. Maybe try

```
<Typical loop={Infinity} wrapper={'span'}
    steps={['Coding', 2000,'Soccer', 2000, 
        'Basketball', 2000, 'Finance', 2000,
        'Tech', 2000]}/>
```